Reading zipped csv and adding new lines
I have a zip file t.zip containing two csv files. The first one is s.csv (30kB) and the other is p.csv (60GB).
What I'm doing now is unzipping p.csv to the disk, reading the second last line, doing some logic and then adding new lines to p.csv. After that I'm zipping the file again.
Is there a better way to do this? Somithing without unzipping to disk an zipping again?
I'm using Python 3.12 and Pandas.
Thanks a lot!

You cannot avoid unzipping the file - the data has to be decompressed to be able to use it. That said, you might want to look at something like a parquet file format for compression, whilst still being amenable to the dataframe format.

You might consider instead appending entries to the zip file with the additional data. That would be much, much faster than unzipping and re-zipping a 60GB file. You would need have control of and update the consuming application to look for additional files after p.csv, and consider them to contain additional rows that follow the rows in p.csv. Reading the data in p.csv to get to your second-to-last row will still take a while, but after doing that twice your second-to-last row will be in a smaller appended entry that can be read very quickly.

I would, instead, break up the p.csv file into many zip entries, named by the row number of the 60 GB table. E.g. r1-10000.csv, r10001-20000.csv, etc. Then random access and updating within the zip file can be much faster. For your specific operation, you would only need to read and update the last one or two entries

It is possible, but it would take a fair bit of coding and some understanding of the deflate compressed data format used in zip files, as well as the zip file format itself. This requires access to some zlib operations that are not provided in Python's interface to zlib, so you would need to make your own zlib interface. gzappend.c gives an example for how this is done, using the gzip format (not zip).
That would require decoding the entire 60 GB zip file entry every time, though it would not require writing all that to disk or recompressing the whole thing. Just the end of the entry and the zip file central directory would be rewritten in order to append to the entry. I would recommend instead breaking your 60 GB CSV table into many zip file entries for faster access and updating. And then no special functions or interfaces would be needed. You could use the provided Python zip file functions. See my comments on the question.
